# Configure incoming email in share Point 2010 without exchange server

Tags: email, sharepoint-2010

I want to configure incoming email in share Point 2010 without exchange server and without third party tool. Can anyone provide me a link where each and everything is defined with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this guide:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2010/08/16/configuring-incoming-email-for-sharepoint-2010-foundations.aspx

http://johanolivier.blogspot.com/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-incoming-e-mail.html

http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2010/05/installing-smtp-pop3-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: Hi Madhur, thanks for reply. I am already checks all the links which provided by you. please give my best link or document for same.